# Аналог файлов дополнений APK

Tags: android, android-studio, файлы, google-play

В приложении есть несколько частей. Нужно чтобы после загрузки приложения с маркета была доступна только одна. При выборе другой, нужно загружать всю информацию для нее, и так далее. Нужен некий аналог файлов дополнений, так как можно использовать только 1 файл дополнений, а мне нужно порядка 5-10.

**Вариант использовать сторонний сервер не подходит, так как заказчик против.**

Он хочет загружать все исключительно в маркет.

Comment: Instant apps работают по такому принципу, но не уверен что это именно то что ищете: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html

Comment: Вообще то можно использовать 2 expansion файла - основной и патч

Comment: я знаю, но для моей задачи одного патч файла мало. нужно несколько больше((